How can I balance capacity between two AC condensers?
New to HVAC and I want to be more confident in identifying linesets when dealing with two units. The house has two condensers with different tonnage and both supply different areas of the house ex: one does upstairs while the other one supply’s down stairs. The linesets are correct outside on both units.
How can I make sure that correct tonnage is going to the correct coil? For example the bigger tonnage of condenser is not going to the smaller coil and the smaller tonnage is going to the bigger coil in the attic? I have heard the tap method but just curious if there’s other ways?

By "aren't crossed" do you mean liquid and vapor set connect the correct condenser and indoor unit - or crossed as in a condenser having its vapor line going to one indoor unit and its liquid line to the other unit? Are the lines loose or already connected? Charged with refrigerant? Electrically insulated from the building and equipment, by chance?

If you have two separate systems, turn one off and make a call for heat/cooling on the other system. Then go check to make sure the correct condensing unit is running.

This should be fairly easy to determine. Try shutting both units off utilizing the thermostats. Then turn on one unit with a thermostat. Find the air handler that is running and then find the condenser that's running. Check the name plate rating for each. The larger condenser should be running with the larger air handler or the smaller condenser running with the smaller air handler, depending on with one you turned on. This will also verify that the right thermostat is running the right unit, that the upstairs thermostat isn't running the downstairs unit.
